# Babel CLI change Filenames of out-dir

Tags: javascript, babeljs

**Problem:**

Because I need to differentiate between es5 and es6> files in my folders, I'm in need of a way to rename files transpliced by babel.
I'm using @babel/cli and @babel/core 7.4.4

Currently i use babel like this:

`npx babel dev --out-dir serv --watch`

I'd need a way to tell the file i.e. `dev/test.js` something like

`npx babel dev --out-dir serv --watch --fileNameAppend=".es5"`

to result in `serv/test.es5.js` (essentially just something different than the original name).

Is there a way to achieve this in the current babel version?

A similar Question exists here, however i can not use the extension .es6:
[How do you change the file names output from babel-cli in directory mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43369099/how-do-you-change-the-file-names-output-from-babel-cli-in-directory-mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [v7.8.0](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v780-2020-01-12) you can use [babel-cli](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli)'s `--out-file-extension` flag:

```
npx babel dev --out-dir serv --watch --out-file-extension .es5.js
```

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli#set-file-extensions